# Ubuntu not Starting (smbus is busy can't use it)

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu along with Windows 11. It was working perfectly, but after I once restarted Windows and then selected Ubuntu OS, it gives following error:

Transaction Timeout
Failed terminating the transaction
smbus is busy can't use it

Comment: Restarting to change operating systems does not always work, as Windows will leave some hardware in an intermediary state. You may have better luck if you shut down (not reboot), *then* boot the machine when switching between operating systems.