# Ubuntu Error: Transaction timeout, failed terminating the transaction, SMbus is busy can't use it

Tags: reboot, 22.10

After run cmd reboot I cannot login to Ubuntu and the system always shows this message.

```
Transaction timeout
Failed terminating the transaction
SMbus is busy can't use it.
```

It always shows black screen with the logo.

Comment: Duplicates https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388861/ubuntu-not-starting-smbus-is-busy-cant-use-it ?